# CUDA: unified memory, using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, cuda, operator-overloading

I'm trying to get unified memory to work with classes, and to pass and manipulate arrays in unified memory with kernel calls. I want to pass everything by reference.

So I'm overriding the new method for classes and arrays so they are accessible by the GPU, but I think I need to add more code to have arrays in unified memory, but not quite sure how to do this. I get a memory access error when the fillArray() method is called.

If I have to do these sorts of operations (arithmetic on arrays and copying between different sized arrays) hundreds of times, is unified memory a good approach or should I stick with manually copying between cpu and gpu memory? Thank you very much!

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


#define TILE_WIDTH 4

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER __host__ __device__
#else
#define CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER
#endif

__global__ void add1(int height, int width, int *a, int *resultArray)
{
    int w = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // Col // width
    int h = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int index = h * width + w;

    if ((w < width) && (h < height))
        resultArray[index] = a[index] + 1;
}

class Managed 
{
public:
    void *operator new(size_t len) 
    {
        void *ptr;
        cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
        return ptr;
    }

    void Managed::operator delete(void *ptr) 
    {
        cudaFree(ptr);
    }

    void* operator new[] (size_t len) {
        void *ptr; 
        cudaMallocManaged(&ptr, len);
        return ptr;
    }
        void Managed::operator delete[] (void* ptr) {
        cudaFree(ptr);
    }
};

class testArray : public Managed
{
public: 
    testArray()
    {
        height = 16;
        width = 8;
        myArray = new int[height*width];
    }
    ~testArray()
    {
        delete[] myArray;
    }

    CUDA_CALLABLE_MEMBER void runTest()
    {
        fillArray(myArray);
        printArray(myArray);

        dim3 dimGridWidth((width - 1) / TILE_WIDTH + 1, (height - 1)/TILE_WIDTH + 1, 1);
        dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH, TILE_WIDTH, 1);

        add1<<<dimGridWidth,dimBlock>>>(height, width, myArray, myArray);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        printArray(myArray);
    }

private:

    int *myArray;
    int height; 
    int width;

    void fillArray(int *myArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                myArray[i*width+j] = i*width+j;
        }
    }

    void printArray(int *myArray)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                printf("%i ",myArray[i*width+j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    testArray *test = new testArray;
    test->runTest();

    //testArray test;
    //test.runTest();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is very simple: `myArray` is allocated on the host, not as unified memory.

The reason for that is that while `testArray` dervies from `Managed` (and thus your `testArray *test = new testArray` allocates unified memory), the allocation that is being done inside its constructor allocates an array of `int`s, which are not derived from `Managed`.

Therefore your pointer lives in unified memory, but points to host memory.

Just off the top of my mind, the following should help:

```
struct UnifiedInt : int, Managed { /* implement a few convenience functions */ };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple but I didn't know how to do it. Anyway if you change this line of code:

```
myArray = new int[height*width];
```

to the following, it looks like it works.

```
cudaMallocManaged(&myArray, height * width * sizeof(int));
```

If you have another way of doing this, I'd be interested in seeing it.